# SQlite Database error: CursorIndexOutofBounds?

Tags: android, sqlite

My application is crashing due to an issue with the database. I am unsure what is causing the issue. Below is more detail.

I am getting the following error in **Logcat:**

```
07-24 19:05:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(23786): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-24967
07-24 19:05:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(23786): Process: com.example.brianapp, PID: 23786
07-24 19:05:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(23786): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
07-24 19:05:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(23786):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
07-24 19:05:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(23786):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
07-24 19:05:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(23786):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
07-24 19:05:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(23786):    at com.example.brianapp.DatabaseHelper.getScore(DatabaseHelper.java:116)
07-24 19:05:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(23786):    at com.example.brianapp.Meditation.writeToDatabase(Meditation.java:626)
07-24 19:05:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(23786):    at com.example.brianapp.Meditation$2.run(Meditation.java:139)
```

It firstly refers to **this method** in my database helper class:

```
// Getting single score (i.e. not the full db)  
    Score getScore(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SCORE, new String[] {COL_SESSION, COL_GAMETITLE, 
                COL_NAME, COL_MED, COL_MAX, COL_AVGATT, COL_MAXATT, COL_SCORE, COL_DATE }, COL_SESSION + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(name) }, null, null,null,null); 
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Score score = new Score(Integer.parseInt(cursor
                .getString(0)),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),Integer.parseInt(cursor
                .getString(3)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)),
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)),
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)), cursor.getString(8));
        // return contact
        return score;
    }
```

and also to **this code section** where I use this method in another activity:

```
public void writeToDatabase(){

            DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);



            /**
             * CRUD Operations
             * */

            SimpleDateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //change back to original if not working (see SO)

            //myDate will be used to enter into DB
            String myDate= df.format(new Date()); 


            //getting random number for sessionid (WILL BE CHANGED EVENTUALLY)
            Random ran = new Random();
            int x = ran.nextInt(1) + 3000;

            //Adding the new Score to the database. NOTE: SESSIONID NEEDS TO BE SORTED
            db.addScore(new Score(x, "Multiplication", UserName.getUserName(), averageMedLevel,medMax, 
                    averageAttLevel,attMax, score,myDate));

            //single score, used for passing to the results screen
            single = db.getScore(UserName.getUserName());


            //list of all the scores in the database
            List<Score> scores = db.getAllScores();
```

Comment: you cursor is empty, meaning there is no line that matches the query. i would look into the `addScore` method to make sure it actually saves something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the query does not return any data, there is no first row to move to, and `moveToFirst()` returns `false`.
You have to check this:

```java
Cursor cursor = db.query(...);
if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // nothing found in DB
    return null; // or whatever is appropiate for this error
}
... cursor.getXxx() ...
return score;
```

(Note: `query()` never returns `null`.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your cursor is empty, I'd suggest you only read data from the cursor when is not null. In your code you already have all you need for this. Just make the next changes:

```
Score getScore(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SCORE, new String[] {COL_SESSION, COL_GAMETITLE, 
            COL_NAME, COL_MED, COL_MAX, COL_AVGATT, COL_MAXATT, COL_SCORE, COL_DATE }, COL_SESSION + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(name) }, null, null,null,null); 
    //Just add brackets to this validation so you only read the Cursor when is not empty
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        Score score = new Score(Integer.parseInt(cursor
            .getString(0)),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),Integer.parseInt(cursor
            .getString(3)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)),
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)),
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)), cursor.getString(8));

        return score;
    }
    //Otherwise return null or change this to whatever you want
    else
        return null
}
```

Comment: is it to do with the parameters, my primary key is no longer a string value, will this affect the method?

Comment: This should be the solution. If you have a `Score` that you got using `getScore` and it's `null` then you shouldn't use it anywhere.